# How do I return a valid ETag in a message's response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, etag

I have developed an ASP.NET Core middleware solution that calculates the value of the ETag that matches the `GET` request I am performing and returns it in the response.

The relevant code excerpt is below:

```
RequestHeaders requestHeaders = new RequestHeaders(actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers);
ResponseHeaders responseHeaders = new ResponseHeaders(actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers);

// return not modified for conditional GET and HEAD
if (requestHeaders.IfNoneMatch != null && (requestHeaders.IfNoneMatch.Any(val => val.Tag == eTag || val.Tag == "*")))
{
    responseHeaders.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue(eTag);
    actionContext.Result = new ObjectResult(null) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified };
    return;
}

responseHeaders.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue(eTag);
responseHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600), Private = false };
```

With this code, I am successfully able to return an ETag response in the HTTP message, as well as get that ETag into an `If-Match` or `If-None-Match` header for subsequent responses.

However, there is some C# particularity I am missing, as when testing via Swagger, the headers of the response have weird formatting, as if I was doing a `.ToString()` on the C# property:

```
...
"date": "Tue, 24 Oct 2017 15:08:39 GMT",
"etag": "\"c96GUyc4QBo5w(...)ggSdPkEdgB1i56Qcs=\"",
"server": "Kestrel",
...
```

Is there a way to avoid the escaped `\"` in the HTTP response headers, or should I just ensure my clients all understand this limitation and properly parse the string?

When sending the other headers, the input format is the string without the `\"`, which would make for a lot of extra conversion effort.

EDIT:
I discovered an alternative way to set the ETag that's less direct and doesn't check types (i.e. I don't have to use an `EntityTagValue` and can use a string directly)

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ETag] = eTag;
```

This way, the string is not escaped, and I can copy-paste it directly into further requests.

Comment: It seems my recollection in my previous answer was incorrect, but re-reading, what's the problem here? E-tags have to have quotes around them and `ToString()` on headers escape those quotes. What's wrong?

Comment: The only issue is that if I was going to copy this header directly into another request (i.e. curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'If-None-Match: "\"c96GUyc4QBo5w(...)ggSdPkEdgB1i56Qcs=\""' ... ), the request would fail. If that's how it's supposed to work and I have to do the manual work to parse the escaped string, I'll work with that.

Comment: Looking into it further,   `"etag": "\"c96GUyc4QBo5w(...)ggSdPkEdgB1i56Qcs=\""` seems to be the way to represent a string with " in a JSON object. @JonHanna can you post your comment as a top-level answer so I can accept it as the response? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of how `ToString()` represents things. Because it gives a JSON form, quotes are escaped, and because E-Tags require quotes (except for `*`), the result is that there are escaped quotes. The quotes are not escaped as actual E-Tag headers in the HTTP though.